# undefined method `article' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I'm trying to implement notifications when a user comments on an article. I have followed this tutorial https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications

but i have no idea why there is no association recognized between article and notification. Copying and pasting "Notification.first.notifiable.article" in the rails console produces a result.

Error message [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdIUv.png)

index.json.jbuilder in notifications view folder:

require "json"

```
json.array! @notifications do |notification|
  json.id notification.id
  json.unread !notification.read_at?
  json.template render partial: "notifications/#{notification.notifiable_type.underscore.pluralize}/#{notification.action}", locals: {notification: notification}, formats: [:html]


end
```

**UPDATE:**

_posted.html.erb (the partial that thie line of code will render:
json.template render partial: "notifications/#{notification.notifiable_type.underscore.pluralize}/#{notification.action}"....)

```
<%= link_to article_path(notification.notifiable.article, anchor: dom_id(notification.notifiable)), class: "dropdown-item #{"unread" if !notification.read_at?}" do %>
  <%= notification.actor.name %>
  <%= notification.action %>
  a <%= notification.notifiable_type.underscore.humanize.downcase %>
<% end %>
```

Notifications controller

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
    def index 
        @notifications = Notification.where(recipient: current_user)
    end 

    def mark_as read 
      @notifications = Notification.where(recipient: current).unread 
      @notifications.update.all(read_at: Time.zone.now)
      render json: {success: true}
    end 
end
```

Comments controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_article
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]

  def create
    @comment = @article.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        Notification.create!(recipient: @article.user, actor: current_user, action: "posted", notifiable: @comment)
        redirect_to @article
      else
        redirect_to @article
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    end

    def set_comment
      @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    end

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
end
```

Comment: Add your `_posted.html.erb` and controller.

Comment: Apparently, not all your notifications are assigned to notifiables.

Comment: Added the partial and contoller.

Comment: Considering your code, I suppose you have a `belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true` in your `Notification` class. The fact you have an `undefined method 'article' for nil:NilClass` error means your current `notification` object doesn't have its `notifiable` defined (duh!). That's why I suspect your `Notification.first.notifiable.article` test isn't enough (you could try to display another object than the first Notification for example). Also, you should check that these values are really defined by adding `<% raise notification.inspect %>` before your `<%= link_to article_path ...`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `<% puts notification.inspect %>` (because this is an **index** page)

Comment: Thank you @romainsalles, that helped!  i entered the command rails db:setup to reset the database and tested again and it works now.

Comment: I'm glad it helps :)